# Check if all leaves are at same level in a binary tree

Tags: java, tree

I have written this code for checking whether all leaves are in the same level or not, in a binary tree. Any suggestion or improvement is appreciated.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Methods {      

    //* ---- Method for check whether all leaves are in the same level or not --- *         
    public static boolean leavesIn1Level(Node root){

        if(root == null){
            return false;
        }           
        if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
            return true;
        }
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();     
        q.add(root);

        int levelNumber = 0;
        int height = height(root);

        while(true){

            int nodeCount = q.size();           
            if(nodeCount == 0){
                break;
            }   
            while(nodeCount > 0){

                Node current = q.remove();
                nodeCount--;

                if(current.left == null && current.right == null){
                    if(height != levelNumber){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                if(current.left != null){
                    q.add(current.left);
                }
                if(current.right != null){
                    q.add(current.right);
                }           
            }           
            levelNumber++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //* ---- Method for finding height of a binary tree ---- *  
    public static int height(Node root){

        if(root == null){
            return -1;

        }else{

            return Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right))+1;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node root1 = new Node(8);                      //              8
        root1.left = new Node(9);                      //             / \
        root1.right = new Node(5);                     //            9   5                           
        root1.left.left = new Node(4);                 //           /   /
        root1.right.left = new Node(1);                //          4   1
        root1.right.left.left = new Node(3);           //             /
        root1.right.left.left.left = new Node(2);      //            3                  
                                                       //           /
                                                       //          2

        Node root2 = new Node(1);                      //              1
        root2.left = new Node(2);                      //             /  \
        root2.right = new Node(3);                     //           2     3
        root2.left.left = new Node(4);                 //          / \   /
        root2.left.right = new Node(5);                //        4    5 6 
        root2.right.left = new Node(6);


        System.out.println(leavesIn1Level(root1));
        System.out.println(leavesIn1Level(root2));
   }
}
```

`Node` class:

```
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;     
    public Node(int d){
        data = d;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

This code is different from:
[Check if all leaves are at same level](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58455/check-if-all-leaves-are-at-same-level)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay lets start with the name of your function: `leavesIn1Level(...)`. It *does* explain what this method does, but apparently it is not very clear - even to yourself - therefore you felt the need to add a comment. How a bout the name `areAllLeavesInSameLevel(..)`. This explais what it does and makes your comment useless.

Next point (a compliment): You used a Queue, which is the data-structure that fits your needs perfectly. Good job.

One thing I noticed: The line `node.left == null && node.right == null` is used twice in your short piece of code and therefore - **code duplication**. How do we get rid of it? Well... What does that line of code do? It checks whether a `Node` is a Leaf. So why don't we just name it that way?

```
private static boolean isLeaf(Node node)
{
    return node.left == null && node.right == null;
}
```

Boom. Code duplication gone. **And** the code explains exactly what it does.

Now what I realized, is that you have a very deep level of abstraction in this function, where you mix *what* is done with *how* its done. Lets try to get rid of this:

```
if(current.left != null){
    q.add(current.left);
}
if(current.right != null){
    q.add(current.right);
}
```

This piece of code explains how something is done. But what is done? Children of a node are added to a queue. Why don't we just name it that?

```
private static void addChildrenToQueue(Node node, Queue<Node> queue)
{
    if(node.left != null){
        queue.add(node.left);
    }
    if(node.right != null){
        queue.add(node.right);
    }    
}
```

Lets take a look at what we have now:

```
public static boolean areAllLeavesInSameLevel(Node root){

    if(root == null){
        return false;
    }           
    if(isLeaf(root)){
        return true;
    }
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>(); 
    q.add(root);

    int levelNumber = 0;
    int height = height(root);

    while(true){

        int nodeCount = q.size();           
        if(nodeCount == 0){
            break;
        }   
        while(nodeCount > 0){

            Node current = q.remove();
            nodeCount--;

            if(isLeaf(current)){
                if(height != levelNumber){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
            addChildrenToQueue(current,q); 
        }           
        levelNumber++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I'm not particularly happy with the name `q`. What is inside that queue? It's nodes that need to be checked - in other words: `remainingNodes`. Lets just call it that.

Take a look at this:

```
while(true){
    int nodeCount = remainingNodes.size();           
    if(nodeCount == 0){
        break;
    }
    ...
}
return false;
```

What does it do? If the queue is empty it jumps out of the loop and then returns false. How about we move it around a bit to get rid of that `while(true)`:

```
while(!remainingNodes.isEmpty()){
    int nodeCount = remainingNodes.size(); 
    ...
}
return false;
```

Aaaand the `while(true)` is gone and replaced with a much better phrased condition. While the Collection of remaining nodes is not empty do something. At this point we can argue that the queue could have the even better name `queueOfRemainingNodes`. Some would say it's too long. I like it, but that's up to you to decide.

Let's take a look at the second `while`:

```
int nodeCount = queueOfRemainingNodes.size();   
while(nodeCount > 0){
    nodeCount--;
    ...
}
```

To me this looks like the classic case for a `for`-loop instead:

```
for(int nodeCount = queueOfRemainingNodes.size(); nodeCount > 0; nodeCount--)
{
    ...
}
```

Okay. Now what does this inner for-loop actually do? It checks whether any node, that is currently in the queue is a leaf and if it is not, it adds its children to the queue. If however one *is* a leaf, it does the following check:

```
if(height != levelNumber){
```

What? Is height equal to levelNumber? What is levelNumber? And which height? By looking up we find out that `height` is the height of the tree and `levelNumber` is the number of the level we are *currently* looking at. Let's give these two some more expressive names:

```
int currentLevelNumber = 0;
int treeHeight = height(root);
```

So where are we now? Let's take a look at the full code:

```
public static boolean areAllLeavesInSameLevel(Node root){

    if(root == null){
        return false;
    }           
    if(isLeaf(root)){
        return true;
    }
    Queue<Node> queueOfRemainingNodes = new LinkedList<Node>(); 
    queueOfRemainingNodes.add(root);

    int currentLevelNumber = 0;
    int treeHeight = height(root);

    while(!queueOfRemainingNodes.isEmpty()){

        for(int nodesOnCurrentLevel = queueOfRemainingNodes.size(); nodesOnCurrentLevel > 0; nodesOnCurrentLevel--){

            Node current = q.remove();

            if(isLeaf(current)){
                if(treeHeight != currentLevelNumber){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
            addChildrenToQueue(current,queueOfRemainingNodes); 
        }           
        currentLevelNumber++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Wow. Just realized how long this post got. Sorry, I could go on for hours and remove this second (and third) level of intendation and find more expressive names for everything, but I think this gives you an impression on what you **can** do.

Comment: About the algorithmic aspect, I think that `currentLevelNumber` and `int treeHeight = height(root);` (which is a bit inefficient because it needs to look at the whole tree) could be replaced with a boolean variable `bool leafAlreadyFound`. Then in the `for` loop, use: `if(isLeaf(current)){ leafAlreadyFound = true;} else if(leafAlreadyFound) { return false;} else { addChildrenToQueue(...)}`
And the last line should then be `return true`

Comment: And this addresses the 3 aspects mentionned by @vnp

Comment: @oliverpool absolutely. I didn't really look at the algorithmic aspect at all. If I weren't so busy at the moment I'd love to keep refactoring this code until these algorithmic aspects pop out on their own.

Comment: I just posted an answer, because a comment is not that readable. I totally agree: refactoring helps to understand what the code is actually doing and without your answer, I wouldn't have been able to do such suggestion

Comment: When you were reasoning about converting the inner `while` loop to a `for` loop, it's important to note that this is only possible because the `nodeCount` was never used in the body of that loop. If it were, you wouldn't use the `for` loop because in the `while` loop, `nodeCount` was decremented before the rest of the body of the loop, not after (which would be the case of the `for` loop). In other words, the value of `nodeCount` would be off by one for each iteration of the loop due to the late decrementation.

Answer (score 5):

- **Algorithm**

  A computation of `height` is redundant. The code processes a tree level by level, so the natural continuation condition is that the level contains only non-leaves:

  ```
  while (!q.isEmpty()) {
          ...
          if (isLeaf(current)) {
              leafs++;
          } else {
              add_children();
              internals++;
          }
          if (leafs == 0) {
              continue;
          }
          return internals == 0;
      }
  ```
- **Unreachable code**

  Getting out of the `while (true)` loop via `nodeCount == 0` condition implies that we traversed the whole tree and encountered no leaves. It is logically impossible and if the program follows this path, then there is a bug. Returning `false` would only mask it. Better raise an exception instead.
- **Don't spell out logics**

  Instead of

  ```
              if(height != levelNumber){
                  return false;
              }else{
                  return true;
              }
  ```

  use

  ```
              return height == levelNumber;
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Just improving @LorToso answer (with an answer instead of an unreadable comment):

About the algorithmic aspect, I think that `currentLevelNumber` and `int treeHeight = height(root);` (which is a bit inefficient because it needs to look at the whole tree) could be replaced with a boolean variable `leafAlreadyFound`.

Then the full code could be:

```
public static boolean areAllLeavesInSameLevel(Node root){

    if(root == null){
        return false;
    }           

    boolean leafAlreadyFound = false;
    Queue<Node> queueOfRemainingNodes = new LinkedList<Node>(); 

    queueOfRemainingNodes.add(root);

    while(!leafAlreadyFound && !queueOfRemainingNodes.isEmpty()){

        for(int nodesOnCurrentLevel = queueOfRemainingNodes.size(); nodesOnCurrentLevel > 0; nodesOnCurrentLevel--){

            Node current = q.remove();

            if(isLeaf(current)){
                leafAlreadyFound = true;
            } else if(leafAlreadyFound){
                return false;
            } else {
                addChildrenToQueue(current,queueOfRemainingNodes); 
            }
        }           
    }
    return queueOfRemainingNodes.isEmpty();
}
```

And as a bonus, the specific condition at the beginning is removed

```
    if(isLeaf(root)){
        return true;
    }
```

It addresses all concerned raised by @vnp (and reads as few nodes of the tree as possible)